# Do I need to set `:filetype on` myself in Neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype

As title. I'm a user of Neovim and am trying to learn something very basic. My point is that I don't want to set things that will be enabled by Vim by default. And what's the relation  between

```
:filetype on
:filetype indent on
:filetype plugin on
```

Say I have set the second one do I still need to set the first one? Can I say that the first one is a combination of the second and the third one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:h filetype-overview`

```
Overview:                   *:filetype-overview*
command                     detection   plugin      indent ~
:filetype on                on          unchanged   unchanged
:filetype off               off         unchanged   unchanged
:filetype plugin on         on          on          unchanged
:filetype plugin off        unchanged   off         unchanged
:filetype indent on         on          unchanged   on
:filetype indent off        unchanged   unchanged   off
:filetype plugin indent on  on          on          on
:filetype plugin indent off unchanged   off         off

To see the current status, type: >
    :filetype
The output looks something like this: >
    filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:OFF
```

From `:h nvim-defaults`

```
2. Defaults                             *nvim-defaults*

- Filetype detection is enabled by default. This can be disabled by adding
  ":filetype off" to |init.vim|.
```

As expected, executing `$nvim --clean +filetype` outputs

```
filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and clear reference, now I understand it! (finally need to read these ideas as I'm learning how to use vimtex)